# Two separate JREs for junit and source in eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, ant, junit, java

Below is my project structure.

```
-project
   -sources
       -my.package
             -MyClass.java
   -test
       -my.package
             -MyClassTest.java
```

I want to use JDK version less than 1.5 for my source.

Where as my junit test classes needs latest JDK.

Is there any possibility to use two different JDKs for same project.

```
Current solution: I can configure latest JDK for the project and can compile using different targets one for source and one for test. javac -target.
```

Is that correct way to do? or Please suggest any correct solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want use Java 1.4 - what specific reasons do you have? May be there is an easier approach to achieve what you need.

Comment: @Robert To use auto complete feature, if I set to 1.5 or 6 eclipse/netbeans will generate code which will not be compatible with lower jdk versions.

Answer (score 2):

In an Ant build, you can freely specify different JDK and compiler settings for different source folders.

But for Eclipse compilation, I think you will be restricted to using one JDK and compiler settings per-project. I don't think you can specify separate compiler per folder in an Eclipse project.

Options:

- Treat these folders as separate Eclipse projects. Or,
- Implement Ant build for both folders, but Eclipse build only for one of them. For
  example, your junit classes would be built by Ant only.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Second solution wont work, below is one example.
    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @PrepareForTest(
    Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater.

I cann't map my JRE to 1.5.